# Serve as (the) chairman

Tags: articles

Context: "He served as (the) chairman of the committee of the festival since its origin."

As far as I know, no article is needed when we speak about positions that are one-of-a-kind, like *president* and *mayor*. But do we need an article with "serve as" in more general contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. If [**Google Ngrams**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=served+as+chairman%2Cserved+as+the+chairman%2Cserved+as+chair&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cserved%20as%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cserved%20as%20the%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cserved%20as%20chair%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cserved%20as%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cserved%20as%20the%20chairman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cserved%20as%20chair%3B%2Cc0) can be believed, "served as chairman" has been more common for a long time.

But be aware that "chairman" may have sexist connotations. Unless you have a good reason not to do so, I recommend "served as chair." Google also indicates that this genderless version has gained popularity in the last few decades.

On a side note, use "has served" with "since." With the simple past that you have chosen, you would be more likely to write something like this:

> He served as chair of the committee of the festival from its origin until 2019.

The following is more succinct and eliminates the repetition of "of":

> He chaired the committee of the festival from its origin until 2019.

Obviously, such a change alters the nature of my response. There is nothing inherently wrong with "served."

Should "Committee of the Festival" be capitalized as I show it here? If that its official name, then the caps are probably required.

Comment: thanks! The person has passed away, that's why I'm using past simple.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: You might add that such NPs are called 'bare role NPs'. Further, such NPs cannot occur as subjects or objects: in these positions they require a determiner.