# Omission of article 'The'

Tags: definite-article

Is it mandatory to omit article 'The' in this following sentence?

'Mr. Biswas is *the* principal of this school.'

Comment: On the contrary, it is needed in standard English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no article for "president" in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305541/) Also [Why is there no article for "president" in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305541/) and [Serve as (the) chairman](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/291738/) and [Is it correct to say (They elected him as a chairman)?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/300680/), among others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers to be elected president (no article) is not the same as to be the principal of a school.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so we can say both sentences with or without 'the' are correct. It's not mandatory to drop the 'the'.

Comment: @Lambie it's a question of my exam. Options are 'the' or no article. I have chance to challenge my examiner. If both the options are right then we all will get the mark for this question.

Comment: @ArindamBiswas: It's good that you can "challenge" the examiner. See the chart linked to in my second comment, (for "headmaster", but syntactically speaking "principal" is the same; it's just not used much in British English). The chart clearly shows not only that the article is *optional* - it's also obvious that historically it *wasn't* usually included (but according to the chart, both versions are now equally likely). People can argue about whether the usage shift *now* represents some kind of shift in *meaning* (unlikely, imho), but clearly both versions are / have been used extensively.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. Now I got my answer!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "The Education Outlook, Volumes 70-72 (1919), p. 29: Mr. R. B. Henderson , headmaster of the Strand School, Brixton Hill, has been appointed headmaster of Alleyn's School, Dulwich.". My old school, but much later!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150680/discussion-on-question-by-arindam-biswas-omission-of-article-the); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.